# Linear Diophantine Equations - particular solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

So I get that you can determine the general solutions for a linear diophantine equation of the for $ax + by = c$ as:

$$x = x' + \frac{b}{\gcd(a,b)}\cdot t~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~y = y' - \frac{a}{\gcd(a,b)}\cdot t$$

Where $t$ is an integer and $x'$ and $y'$ are the particular solutions.

My question is, how do you determine the particular solutions $x'$ and $y'$. I just sort of guess them, try to plug something in the simplified equation after I determine that $c$ is divisible by the $\gcd(a,b)$ so we have integer solutions.

Is there a method, or some kind of rule that is used that I'm not aware of ?

Comment: Take a look at the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).